# Use MX records to forward all mail to specific server

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I have two domains, lets call them example.com and example.de

I need to have all emails sent to an (any) example.de address being forwarded to the example.com email server. Is it enough to place an MX record for the example.de domain pointing to the email server of the example.com domain?

Specifically:

The example.com A record point everything to my webserver at (for the sake of the argument) 123.123.123.123 The MX records of example.com now points to user1.examplehoster.com This all works perfectly.

Now, how do I set up the MX record for the example.de domain? Because setting it to user1.examplehoster.com does not do the trick apparently :(

Comment: An `MX` record only tells which host is supposed to receive mail for the domain, but the server also needs to be accepting mail for that domain: it needs to be configured to do something with it, whether it's local delivery, relay, forward...

Comment: that I am aware of. still, the email seems to be not even forwarded to the .com domain using the setup described above?

Comment: Any error messages might prove useful, from mail server logs or testing tools like this one https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3agmail.com+&run=toolpage without that I would say it is hard to debug a DNS issue of an unknown domain

Comment: I got a SERVFAIL error due to the fact that the registrar did not put any of my DNS records configured on the nameservers...
See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, apparently this was a problem of the registrar that did not register the domain in the DNS - or at least did not put any resource records in there.

Anyhow, the solution I described above works. Your records will need to be something like this for this to work:

```
example.de IN CNAME example.com
example.com IN A 123.123.123.123
example.de IN MX user1.examplehoster.com
example.com IN MX user1.examplehoster.com
```

This sets example.de as a form of alias for example.com, which will resolve to 123.123.123.123. Emails are forwarded to the examplehoster.com emailserver